# Show 4 latest posts from a specific tag in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, tags, wordpress-theming

I want to show 4 latest posts from tag "video" in WordPress, how can i do this?

I tried this loop but all i want only 4 latest posts.

```
<?php query_posts('tag=video'); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        no video
   <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: please look at my answer, It will solve your problem. Let me know if you still facing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try below Code:**

```
   <?php

            $query = new WP_Query( array(
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                'no_found_rows'  => true,
                'tag'            => 'video'
            ) );

            if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

                while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

                    // the_title();

                endwhile; 

                wp_reset_postdata();

            endif; 
     ?>
```